# A system design that takes a stateful architecture to stateless, monolith to microservices, and also speed of transactions

Tags: architecture, microservices, system-design, inventory-management

I am working with a product that performs inventory transactions using Oracle ERP's SCM APIs.

The model is a simple client-server model. The client is a very thin native application that communicates to the server using web socket calls and renders views. That's it.

The server, on the other hand, stores the JSON structure of the entire "page" for each transaction. On each event, the client tells the server that this is the event that happened. The server reads this, and with the help of the database, it sends the RIB JSON to the client which renders the view.

Coming down to the individual pages, there is code written on each button, and field's on exit or on key press. The server uses an interpreter to analyze this code and form a new view after every time and sends it back to the client to render that view.

My question is, can this be taken to a microservice architecture? And since inventory transactions need to be really fast, I'm confused about what communication protocol is to be used. Because if I propose microservices, they say that REST is pretty slower than web sockets.

And in the stateful architecture, they're storing session ID and stuff like that. I am not sure if I can move to stateless.

Lastly, if the microservice thing does work out, should we maintain the very inactive client that is just rendering views, or should we upgrade it and make it do some stuff that the server is doing.

I just didn't know where to ask these questions that are specific to the current architecture of the product. Plus I have been assigned to take decisions on how to integrate new technologies or if it is even possible to do so.

Comment: What makes you think microservices imply REST?

Comment: Hi Levi...No...microservices just don't mean REST...I did say that should we even move to microservices in such an architecture? And if yes, then what should be used for communication. If not REST. And if REST, what technologies can I use to make it at par with the current architecture. Like maybe thickening the client a little bit, or introducing something like a message broker or something.